# Scipy interpolate/extrapolate spline

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline, extrapolation

I had a working python code that generates an interpolating function from row data:

```
scipy.interpolate.interp1d(Static_V_E[:,0], Static_V_E[:,1], kind =  INTERP_KIND, bounds_error=False, fill_value="extrapolate")
```

It was working with `INTERP_KIND = "cubic"` and it worked until a few days ago (I do not remember if I updated scipy/anaconda or something else). However, now the code crashes with the error:

`ValueError: Extrapolation does not work with kind=spline`

And I have to replace it with `INTERP_KIND = "linear"`.
This, of course, leads to much worse results in my calculation. Is there any way to have a better interpolation than the linear one, possibly without changing the syntax? (I have this function called hundred of times in the code, and I which to be able just to change INTERP_KIND or something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your scipy. Cubic etc kinds extrapolate just fine from at least scipy 0.19.0.

Comment: This solved the problem. I do not know why my version of scipy was downgraded to 0.18.0. Thanks a lot